# How to handle error records in Batch apex?

Tags: apex, batch

I have a simple requirement to write a batch which will loop through all the records for 'Object__c' and update a custom field on the object(Logic is irrelevant here).

Here is the batch class I developed:

```
public class SimpleBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id,Name,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c,Active__c FROM 
                        Object__c WHERE Start_Date__c!=NULL AND End_Date__c!=NULL');
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Package__c> scope){
        Date todayDate = Date.today();
        List<Object__c> objsToUpdate = new List<Object__c>();
        for(Object__c obj:scope){
            if((obj.Start_Date__c <= todayDate) && (obj.End_Date__c >=todayDate)){
                if(pkgObj.Active__c != 'Yes'){
                    pkgObj.Active__c = 'Yes';
                    objsToUpdate.add(obj);
                }
            }else if((obj.Start_Date__c > todayDate) || (obj.End_Date__c < todayDate)){
                if(obj.Active__c != 'No'){
                    obj.Active__c = 'No';
                    objsToUpdate.add(obj);
                }
            }
        }
        update objsToUpdate;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        //code to send email that batch finished successfully.
    }

}
```

Lets assume there are 1000 records to process and I am running the job with a batch size of 200 records.

1. Batch 1 - First set of 200 records - Records failed with validation
   errors.
2. Batch 2 - Second set of 200 records - Records failed with
       validation errors.
3. Batch 3 - Third set of 200 records - Records
           failed with validation errors.
4. Batch 4 - Fourth set of 200 records -
               Records failed with validation errors.
5. Batch 5 - Fifth set of 200
                   records - successfully processed, No errors.

**Here is the problem:** Even though first batches failed, The email is sent from the finish method saying that batch successfully processed.

Only When I look into the logs, I will know that there are some records failed otherwise everything looks to seem fine even though 4 batches failed.

Any best practices or advice on how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some things to do:

1. Have your batch class implement Database.stateful
2. Declare some variables that are initialized in the constructor to 0. These variables count successes and errors; also a string variable that remembers the records that failed and why (initialized to empty string).
3. Use `Database.update` with `allOrNothing` = `false` instead of `update` within `execute()`. Interrogate each member of `Database.SaveResult[]` for `isSuccess()` and count succcesses and failures in your stateful variables from #2.  Log in the stateful variable all the errors (id of record, name of record, and error message/exception)
4. In the `finish` method, send an email to the sysad of count of successes/failures + string variable of all the failures.
5. In `finish()` method, write your batch results to a custom `Log__c` record(s)

Comment: Decent answer, but two additions: query the job Id in the finish method, to check for blown governor limits, and use a try catch block in the execute method to catch whatever unusual exceptions may occur that one can catch, so they can be recorded properly.

Comment: try-catch - yes, of course; as for querying the `ApexAsyncJob` in `finish()` - I never thought of that before to catch limits exceptions - so thanks! Also, I'd probably redo the logging approach if batch was huge and incidence of errors was high to avoid blowing heap

Answer (score 13):

1. first of all you need to make your batch class stateful using **Database.Stateful** so replace your first line with

   ```
   public class SimpleBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.Stateful{
   ```
2. A global variable required which will maintain failed record.

   ```
   global List<String> exception_List;
   ```
3. Use **[Database.update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_update)** method instead of update with allOrNothing = false parameter which will return how many records has passed and failed in update call.

   ```
   Database.SaveResult[] SaveResultList = Database.update(objsToUpdate,false);
   ```
4. You will iterate saveResultList and you will add failed records in exception_list

   ```
    for(integer i =0; i<objsToUpdate.size();i++){
           String msg='';
           If(!SaveResultList[i].isSuccess()){
                   msg += userList.get(i).id + '\n'+'Error: "';        
                   for(Database.Error err: SaveResultList[i].getErrors()){  
                        msg += err.getmessage()+'"\n\n';
                   } 
           }
           if(msg!='')
               exception_List.add(msg);
        }
   ```
5. You can use this exception_list in execute method to send in your final email.

Comment: How would we send the `exception_list` in an email? Been trying to find examples but having a hard time

Comment: Using Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm